# Change the strings in student_grade_str into int

Tags: python, keyerror

I wanna change the strings in student_grade_str into int.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')
student_grade_str =pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/student_power_research.csv')      
for i in range( len( student_grade_str)):
  student_grade_int = list(map(int(),student_grade_str[i]))
```

And here's
[student_power_research.csv](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive)（[Picture version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZeom.png)）

I ran this code with google colab. Result is Keyerror: 0. I don't understand what that error means.
Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Maybe try adding the argument `dtype=int` to your `read_csv` statement? And also `header=0`. Then you can get rid of the `for` loop entirely. (It'll be faster, too!) [This documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
student_grade_str = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/student_power_research.csv')                  
student_grade_str = student_grade_str["Number"].astype(int)
student_grade_str = student_grade_str["Language"].astype(int)
student_grade_str = student_grade_str["Logic"].astype(int)
```

No need of for loop to convert string to int. Change your code as above.